# animation-delay in IOS not working correctly

Tags: android, ios, css, uiwebview

So I know that JS setInterval has issues in ios and android. I recently found that animation-delay in css also has issues. I have a loading spinner that has 8 dots that grow/shrink and the spinner spins. So at the start the top dot gets the animation to grow, then the next dot has a delay and then the animation is also applied. This makes it looks like it is chasing in a circle of red dots.

Here is a fiddle of the desired look. http://jsfiddle.net/3xjRF/

However on iOS and Android the delays are attached oddly. Sometimes the first 5 dots start animating at the same time or whatever. The key is the delay is either not being respected, rounded, applied at different times.

Any thoughts how to get css animation-delay to work properly in iOS webview? I tried using scale3d so it would run in the GPU but even then the delay was still the main issue. I'd like to do it in css vs a gif or what not.

```
#circularG {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  top: 39%;
  z-index: 10000;
}
.circularG {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #d4242c;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 14px;
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce_circularG;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.28s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: linear;
  -moz-animation-name: bounce_circularG;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1.28s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-direction: linear;
  border-radius: 14px;
  -o-animation-name: bounce_circularG;
  -o-animation-duration: 1.28s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-direction: linear;
  -ms-animation-name: bounce_circularG;
  -ms-animation-duration: 1.28s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-direction: linear;
}

#circularG_1 {
  left: 0;
  top: 35px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4800000000000001s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.4800000000000001s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0.4800000000000001s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0.4800000000000001s;
}

#circularG_2 {
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.64s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.64s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0.64s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0.64s;
}

#circularG_3 {
  top: 0;
  left: 35px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.8s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0.8s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

#circularG_4 {
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9600000000000002s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.9600000000000002s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0.9600000000000002s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0.9600000000000002s;
}

#circularG_5 {
  right: 0;
  top: 35px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 1.12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 1.12s;
}

#circularG_6 {
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.28s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.28s;
  -o-animation-delay: 1.28s;
   -ms-animation-delay: 1.28s;
}

#circularG_7 {
  left: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.44s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.44s;
  -o-animation-delay: 1.44s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 1.44s;
}

#circularG_8 {
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 1.6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 1.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce_circularG {
  0% {
-webkit-transform:scale(1)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform:scale(.3)
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce_circularG {
  0% {
    -moz-transform:scale(1)
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform:scale(.3)
  }
}

@-o-keyframes bounce_circularG {
  0% {
    -o-transform:scale(1)
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform:scale(.3)
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes bounce_circularG {
  0%{
    -ms-transform:scale(1)
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform:scale(.3)
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: *Slightly off-topic:* since I've noticed unusual time intervals in your code (e.g. `0.9600000000000002s`), I must ask: is your animation code automated? If yes, what software did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issues was related to when the css was applied to the dom. To get around this Instead of using the same animation with a different delay for each elem, I used a keyframe animation for each elem that useds a keyframe offset. This allowed the dom to apply the animations and not have to worry about delay. This took a bit more css but works in ios. It's a bit ugly and keep in mind you have to prefix with all the browsers so you need a -wekbit and so on. You can see how each dot has a different offset and the last few have starting offsets so it makes a full rotation

```
@-ms-keyframes bounce_circularG1 {
  0% {
    -ms-transform:scale(1)
  }
  40%, 100% {
    -ms-transform:scale(.3)
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes bounce_circularG2 {
  13.5% {
    -ms-transform:scale(1)
  }
  0%, 12.5%, 43.5%, 100% {
    -ms-transform:scale(.3)
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes bounce_circularG3 {
  26% {
    -ms-transform:scale(1)
  }
  0%,25%, 46%, 100% {
    -ms-transform:scale(.3)
  }
}
-ms-keyframes bounce_circularG4 {
  38.5% {
    -ms-transform:scale(1)
  }
  0%, 37.5%, 78.5%,100% {
    -ms-transform:scale(.3)
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes bounce_circularG5 {
  51% {
    -ms-transform:scale(1)
  }
  0%, 50%, 91%,100% {
    -ms-transform:scale(.3)
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes bounce_circularG6 {
  63.5% {
    -ms-transform:scale(1)
 }
  3.5%, 62.5% {
    -ms-transform:scale(.3)
  }
  0%, 100% {
    -ms-transform:scale(.37)
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes bounce_circularG7 {
  76% {
    -ms-transform:scale(1)
  }
  16%, 75%{
    -ms-transform:scale(.3)
  }
  0%, 100% {
    -ms-transform:scale(.58)
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes bounce_circularG8 {
  88.5% {
    -ms-transform:scale(1)
  }
  29.5%, 87.5% {
    -ms-transform:scale(.3)
  }
  0%, 100% {
    -ms-transform:scale(.80)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Weird, the first time I looked at it in Chrome they all pulsed at the same time.  But when I re-opened the window they finally staggered in a circle.

My idea (that's way out there) is that perhaps it has to do with the DOM being parsed and CSS being parsed and applied and that messes with the animation delay.  Perhaps you could wait until the DOM is ready and then apply a parent class that will then apply the animations at that point?   It's a weird idea and I have no idea if it will work.

Have you done any other tests with animation-delay on iOS and Android?  (I have small stuff I'm doing and haven't noticed any issues with it, but I'm using whole number delay values.

Comment: same here. didn't work first time, but when I opened again It was working.

Comment: Ya it works on all browsers but in mobile it doesn't. I'm pretty sure its because the class is being added to the dom elements uneven vs all at once so the delay is off. I'll try the doc ready. I also think it's due to limitations of speed on mobile so this could contribute to the dom loading slowly and unexpected errors.

Comment: So I put in a jquery doc ready that would add the animation class to the spinner elems. But even then the delay was not respected on mobile. I had to make 8 animation, one for each dot then set keyframes to achieve a similar effect. Not sure why animation-delay doesnt work

Comment: That is really bizarre, I'll keep my eyes open to see if others are having this issue as well.  

I just had the idea to test it on the iOS simulator on Mac and it works perfectly.  So I really have no idea why you're not seeing it work in the wild.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on iOS 6. Delays are desynced. **Adding the delay property after the *DOM Ready* event didn't work** as well. With no delays all animations seem to run fine, though.

Comment: My solution that works in ios6 and android and web was to use keframes. It took a lot more css to do it since I had to set keyframes for all 8 dots but that works because they are all applied to the dom correctly. So the all get the animation at the same time.

Comment: I added an answer with the css I used to give you an idea. It's sort of messy but works

Answer (score 0):

animation-delay takes a backseat to other iOS performance requirements. As Paul Irish says on [this very topic](https://github.com/benschwarz/gallery-css/issues/7), "scrolling perf trumps spec conformance for the mobile safari team".

A favoured solution appears to be incorporating the delays into individual `@keyframe` rules for each line, as suggested [here](https://github.com/fgnass/spin.js/issues/12) (along with a couple of alternate workarounds).